# Batch rename files including hyphen and everything that follows after

Tags: command-line, rename

I am on Linux and my files look like this:

```
10154-person134_bacteria_640.jpeg         
10163-NORMAL2-IM-0141-0001.jpeg    
10175-person147_bacteria_707.jpeg    
2555-person1_virus_12.jpeg    
25562-person132_bacteria_632.jpeg           
25566-person143_bacteria_687.jpeg
```

I need them to look like this instead:

```
10154.jpeg     
10163.jpeg     
10175.jpeg     
2555.jpeg    
25562.jpeg    
25566.jpeg
```

I tried awk but am running into issues.

Comment: [awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk) is not the tool for rename purposes.

Comment: "running into issues" begs to be explained. What did you try exactly, what results did you had, what did you expected instead?

Answer (score 5):

If you have `perl-rename` (installed as `rename` on many systems, including Debian and Ubuntu), you can do:

```
$ rename -n 's/(.+?)-.*\./$1./' *jpeg
10154-person134_bacteria_640.jpeg -> 10154.jpeg
10163-NORMAL2-IM-0141-0001.jpeg -> 10163.jpeg
10175-person147_bacteria_707.jpeg -> 10175.jpeg
2555-person1_virus_12.jpeg -> 2555.jpeg
25562-person132_bacteria_632.jpeg -> 25562.jpeg
25566-person143_bacteria_687.jpeg -> 25566.jpeg
```

If that shows the output you expect, run the command again without the `-n` to actually rename the files.

Alternatively, you can do it in the shell:

```
$ for file in *jpeg; do echo mv -- "$file" "${file%%-*}.jpeg"; done
mv -- 10154-person134_bacteria_640.jpeg 10154.jpeg
mv -- 10163-NORMAL2-IM-0141-0001.jpeg 10163.jpeg
mv -- 10175-person147_bacteria_707.jpeg 10175.jpeg
mv -- 2555-person1_virus_12.jpeg 2555.jpeg
mv -- 25562-person132_bacteria_632.jpeg 25562.jpeg
mv -- 25566-person143_bacteria_687.jpeg 25566.jpeg
```

Again, if that prints out what you expect, run the command without the `echo` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have rename utility installed, you can roll your own

```
perl -e 'rename $_, s/-.*\././r for @ARGV' ./*.jpeg
```

---

Or, using GNU versions of the sed and xargs tools where we suffix a null byte `\0`
to mitigate problem filenames.

```
printf '%s\0' *.jpeg  |
sed -ze 'p;s/-.*\././' |
xargs -r0 -n2 -t mv --
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to use awk, then

```
#!/bin/sh

files="10154-person134_bacteria_640.jpeg
10163-NORMAL2-IM-0141-0001.jpeg
10175-person147_bacteria_707.jpeg  
2555-person1_virus_12.jpeg 
25562-person132_bacteria_632.jpeg          
25566-person143_bacteria_687.jpeg"

for f in $files; do
  name=`echo $f | awk -F- '{print $1}'`
  echo $name.jpeg
done
```